# Auto adjust label width to the text with auto layout xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I made a label in xcode and i want the label to adjust the text length using auto layout in xcode.
I searched the internet but nothing is working, It's like we can't reach the storyboard because nothing changes when we try something.

Does anyone know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may get a better answer if you provide more information regarding the issue.  Your description is very vague and does not contain any useful information for us to help you.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Is this just a label inside of a view, a table cell, collection cell? Simulator, device?  How did you define your constraints? Is it crashing, stack trace?  If you can provide an example project that re-creates the issue, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience problems with labels in storyboard usually have to do with not having your constraints set up properly in autolayout. I recommend looking through some tutorials (like this http://www.brianjcoleman.com/autolayout-xcode6/) about using autolayout.

Basically, you need to have your label set up so Xcode knows where to put it and how big it will be on all the different screen sizes of iOS devices. If you don't tell it how it should be constrained, Xcode will guess/decide for itself and often will cause the thing to disappear or shrink or something else you don't want.

Anyway goodluck.